# write string to file in goroutine

Tags: go, io, goroutine

I am using go routine in code as follow:

```
c := make(chan string)
work := make(chan string, 1000)
clvl := runtime.NumCPU()

for i := 0; i < clvl; i++ {
    go func(i int) {
        f, err := os.Create(fmt.Sprintf("/tmp/sample_match_%d.csv", i))
        if nil != err {
            panic(err)
        }
        defer f.Close()
        w := bufio.NewWriter(f)
        for jdId := range work {
            for _, itemId := range itemIdList {
                w.WriteString("test")
            }
            w.Flush()
            c <- fmt.Sprintf("done %s", jdId)
        }
    }(i)
}


go func() {
    for _, jdId := range jdIdList {
        work <- jdId
    }

    close(work)
}()

for resp := range c {
    fmt.Println(resp)
}
```

This is ok, but can I all go routine just write to one files? just like this:

```
c := make(chan string)
work := make(chan string, 1000)
clvl := runtime.NumCPU()
f, err := os.Create("/tmp/sample_match_%d.csv")
if nil != err {
    panic(err)
}
defer f.Close()
w := bufio.NewWriter(f)

for i := 0; i < clvl; i++ {
    go func(i int) {

        for jdId := range work {
            for _, itemId := range itemIdList {
                w.WriteString("test")
            }
            w.Flush()
            c <- fmt.Sprintf("done %s", jdId)
        }
    }(i)
}
```

This can not work, error : `panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range`

Comment: seems like you dont wait for your goroutines to finish and by using `defer f.Close()` your filehandle is closed immediately.

Comment: Smells like a race condition. Try running `go build -race` or `go test -race` whichever you are using, add the `-race` flag. Then it will inform you of problems.

Answer (score 3):

- The bufio.Writer type does not support concurrent access.  Protect it with a mutex.
- Because the short strings are flushed on every write, there's no point in using a bufio.Writer.  Write to the file directly (and protect it with a mutex).
- There's no code to ensure that the goroutines complete before the file is closed or the program exits. Use a sync.WaitGroup.